# source/activate python venv from shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a shell script which I run on win10 usin git bash. It calls python under the hood.
For this to work I need to run the following two lines before in git bash:

```
source /c/Mambaforge/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate my_py_venv
bash setup_stuff.sh
bash shell_script_using_python.sh
```

This works. I now wanted to move the first two lines into the `setup_stuff.sh` (which itself does not use python), since it is part of the setup everyday. This does not seem to work. the second script (shell_script_using_python.sh) complains that there is no python. Maybe the source/activation only works within the `setup_stuff.sh`. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Could you provide the interpreter of each script?

Comment: The first two lines modify the current environment. The third line creates a new bash instance with its own environment, and everything that happens there disappears as soon as the command finishes. If you want the effects of the `setup_stuff.sh` script to affect the current environment, you should run it here, not in a new sub-shell. Try `source`ing that setup script.

Comment: As _Poshi_ explains, this is unlikely to work, because  `conda.sh` most likely changes the environment. If it is so important for you to put all the functionality into `setup_stuff.sh`, consider turning this script into a bash function.

Comment: Note that that is effectively what Conda itself does; somewhere along the line a shell function named `conda` is defined (which in turn will invoke the executable `conda` as necessary) so that `conda activate` can effectively work the same as `source my_py_venv/bin/activate`.